Is there a way to dynamically add values inside @Profile() annotation instead of doing something like @Profile({"dev", "SIT"})?
I am interested in keeping a field in cloud config/application properties file like in below example
eg: app.profile="${spring.profiles.active}"
And then read this value in Java code or directly pass it in @Profile() annotation. This will help me in registering and de-registering the component just by restarting the server instead of doing a deployment just to add a "!" operator for de-registering the component. The component has a scheduler. I am trying to create a toggle for this scheduler. I have one active profile per environment and by just adding the below property I can turn off the scheduler from running in the environment I don't want it to run.
de-registering example: app.profile= "!${spring.profiles.active}"
If this approach is not the correct one, Is there a better way to achieve this?
So I have succussfully managed to read the cloud config value in code but unable to pass it to @Profile() as this ony accepting a hardcoded. Dynamic values are not getting resolved

You can "externalize" the value as it described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
Just define the property in application.yml as
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE}

where SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE is OS variable, that can be set in environment as
export SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=any_profile_here

before starting the application

Thanks for answering. That part is already taken care. I am trying to use the "profile" value inside @Profile("${profile}") (this isn't working). I am looking for a solution for this

There are many ways to set profile programmatically. See original source https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html and examples at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles
